# Как асинхронно отправлять HTTPS запросы

Tags: java, spring

с столкнулся с такой проблемой что мне нужно в App потянуть асинхронность, чтобы убрать задержку и увеличить пропускную способность. И так меня есть метод, который с помощью RestTemplate отправляет get запрос в сторонний сервер  и получает наименование компании в list и сохранять

```
    public void saveCompanyDetails() {
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        ResponseEntity<List<CompanyEntity>> rateResponse =
                restTemplate.exchange(iexApiHost + iexApiKey,
                        HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<CompanyEntity>>() {});

        List<CompanyEntity> companyList = rateResponse.getBody();
        if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(companyList)) {
            companyRepository.saveAll(companyList);
        }
    }, fixedPool);
}
```

У меня не получается сделать так чтобы запросы выполнялись асинхронно.   Может кто подскажет как здесь можно потянуть асинхронность ?

Comment: Если у Вас spring-приложение - посмотрите на WebClient. Если нет - можно, например, обернуть запрос в CompletableFuture

Answer (score 0):

Здраствуйте.

Можете использовать эту
[ссылку](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html)

А если можете переведить код на котлин, можете использовать
[коротины](https://metanit.com/kotlin/tutorial/8.1.php)

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)